# Why did Mike shoot through Chow's right hand?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad*, when Mike rescued Chow, who was being held hostage by cartel's hitmen, he asked if the lady to whom Chow spoke in Chinese can drive. When Chow replied that she can drive, Mike shot him through his right hand.

Why did Mike shoot through Chow's right hand?

Comment: @Ankit Sharma - your edit altered my question into a different one rather than improved it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Breaking Bad Wiki](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Duane_Chow),

> Mike Ehrmantraut tracks him down to the building and shoots him in the
>   hand as a consequence for hesitating to inform Gustavo Fring that he
>   was being held hostage by the Juárez Cartel.

That doesn't make much sense, though.  The clip is [here](http://www.amctv.com/breaking-bad/videos/breaking-bad-talked-about-scenes-mikes-killing-spree).  It seems like Mike doesn't completely buy Chow's story about being held against his will, and not being able to return their calls.  Possibly Mike wants to send a message to other business associates who aren't zealous enough in their efforts to escape from similar situations.

Comment: A man shows up at a hospital with a gunshot wound - surely that is going to attract the police's attention, right? Why would Mike want that?

Answer (score -3):

Mike is a psychopath who loves killing people. Gus needs Chow so he couldn't kill him; rather he shoots him in the hand. Little did he know the Chinese women who he recruited to drive Chow to the hospital actually cannot drive and they later crash, resulting in her own death. Chow survives (barely) as he makes appearances in later episodes.